# Can I set the labels in Inbox to show the number of unread messages?

Tags: gmail, email, user-interface, inbox-by-gmail

I use many labels with GMail, and I filter messages so they appear unread under the labels but skip my inbox. In the GMail navigation drawer (the left menu), each label shows the number of unread messages. In Inbox by default, the labels provide no information about unread messages. Is there a way in Inbox to display the number of unread messages for each label?

This remains a problem with Inbox 1.37 (142224063) running on Android 7.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but each label shows it's number of unread messages. The problem is, that it shows them after the name. So if the label name is too long, you won't see the number.

Also, the label name changes to bold if you have any unread messages in it. And there is an option in settings, that sends to the top of the list any labels that have unread messages.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer is not helpful. My Inbox application does not show unread message counts for custom labels, even for short labels (3 characters). No labels show as bold, regardless of the presence of unread messages. In GMail, the labels do show counts. There is no indication of where the setting in Inbox is to move labels with unread messages to the top.